# Как doctrine записывает значения в приватные поля объектов @ORM\Entity

Tags: php, объекты, symfony, doctrine, entity

Сущность *App\Entity\User*, в ней приватное свойство и геттер:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

Где-то (в контроллере, например), получаю объект:

```php
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(\App\Entity\User::class)->find(4);
echo $user->getName();
```

Вопрос: как именно попадает значение в поле `$name`? Ведь оно указано как приватное... Я в качестве самообучения пытаюсь разобраться. Насколько я понимаю, где-то в недрах `->find(4)` должно ведь быть что-то вроде

```php
$obj = new \App\Entity\User;
//...
$obj->name = $dbRow['name']; // или $obj->setName();
//...
return $obj;
```

, но на деле это не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine, если мне не изменяет память, работает с объектами через [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)

Соответственно независимо от наличия или отсутствия методов или видимости свойств, она имеет возможность при гидрации добавить нужные данные в нужные свойства объекта.

Если мы говорим где именно происходит сопоставление данных со свойствами,то это происходит в момент "гидрации". Если вы посмотрите кеш вашего проекта, то в папке с кешем увидите папку с Hydrators, где для каждой вашей сущности сгенерированны гидраторы, а ваш гидрируемый класс там представлен как ClassMetadata
Для ODM он находится вот тут doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php

И если вы его бегло посмотрите, то увидите что там используется \ReflectionClass.

Comment: Спасибо, в общих чертах понял, нашел кеш созданный, разбираюсь =).